# How to append columns dynamically to a .csv file?

Tags: python-2.6

suppose we have the following csv file

**file1.csv**

```
#groups id  owner
abc id1 owner1
abc id2 owner1
bcx id1 owner2
cpa id3 owner1
```

the following script reads `file1.csv`, filters on the first column, `#groups`, and adds extra characters

```
#!/bin/env python2
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import csv
print "enter Path to orignal file"
GROUPS = raw_input() 
print "enter Path to modified file"
WORKING = raw_input() 

def filter_lines(f):
    """this generator funtion uses a regular expression
    to include only lines that have a `abc` at the start
    and NO `gep` throughout the record
    """
    filter_regex = r'^abc(?!gep).*'              
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        m = re.match(filter_regex, line)
        if m:
            yield line           

pat = re.compile(r'^(abc)(?!.*gep.*)') #insert gep in any abc records that dont have gep            

#insert gep 
variable1 = 0  

with open(GROUPS, 'r') as f: 
    with open(WORKING, 'w') as data:
        #next(f)  # Skip over header in input file.
        #filter
        filter_generator = filter_lines(f)
        csv_reader = csv.reader(filter_generator)
        count = 0
        writer = csv.writer(data) #, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL
        for row in csv_reader:
            count += 1
            variable1 = (pat.sub('\\1gep_', row[0])) #modify all filtered records to include gep
            fields = [variable1]
            writer.writerow(fields)

print 'Filtered (abc at Start and NO gep) Rows Count = ' + str(count)
```

for example, `abc` would turn to `abc_gep` and we would write that to another csv file `file2.csv`

so **file2.csv** now contains only:

```
abc_gep
abc_gep
```

good.

now i want to add the rest of the columns where they match with **abc** from file1.csv

how could i do that?

i tried the following

```
fields = [variable1,row[1],row[2]]
```

but this is hardcoding the columns and not dynamic. i am looking for something more like this:

```
fields = [variable1, row[i]]
```

essentially, this is the result im seeking for **file2.csv**:

```
abc_gep id1 owner1
abc_gep id2 owner1
```